# Flash CS5.5 Output Error

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I have been creating a hypermedia player, and i have got to a stage where it is glitching out and it is apparently a...

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at AvalancheCityHypermediaPlayer_fla::MainTimeline/fl_CustomMouseCursor()
```

Here is my code:

```
import flash.events.Event;

cust_cursor.mouseEnabled= false;

cust_cursor.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_CustomMouseCursor);

function fl_CustomMouseCursor(event:Event)

{

    cust_cursor.x = stage.mouseX;

    cust_cursor.y = stage.mouseY;
}

Mouse.hide();
```

I am not sure why it is not working properly, basically when a button is hovered over it is meant to jump to frame 2 and stop, but it is jumping to that frame, and then jumping straight to frame 1 without stopping on frame 2, and stops on frame 1.

Answer (score 0):

**1 .** Your error isn't producing a line number.  You (and I) will find this invaluable for debugging; if in the Flash IDE, you can turn this on in the Publish Settings under swf preferences as a toggle titled "Permit debugging".

**2 .** Is this code inside a class, or in document code (e.g., Flash IDE "Actions" tab)? If it's inside a class, make sure you pass a reference of the stage to the constructor of your class and assign it to an internally persistent variable so that fl_CustomMouseCursor can address it.  By default, classes have no internal way of referencing the stage, and I'm assuming that's what's producing your #1009 error.

For example, inside your class constructor...

```
package com.example {
    public class MyClass {
        private var stage;
        public function MyClass(arg) {
            stage = arg;
        }
    }
}
```

And outside when instantiating the class...

```
var myObj:MyClass = new MyClass(stage);
```

**3 .** If you want your code to stop on a frame, use [`stop();`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html#stop%28%29) or [`gotoAndStop()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html#gotoAndStop%28%29)

**4 .** Finally, if you're compiling with Flash IDE, you can debug this and see exactly which variable in the stack the runtime environment is having issues with.  You can access it from the debug menu or by compiling with `control-shift-enter`.